# SQL Determine if parameter has a value not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I go about using an IF statement to determine if  one parameter has a value then do some work,parameters get query string but it return any record. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAttachment_View]
    @knowid int,
    @actionid int   
AS
    if(@actionid is null)
    begin
        SELECT        
            name, contentType, uploadKnowledgeID AS id
        FROM            
            t_uploadFileForKnowledge
        WHERE        
            (knowledgeID_FK = @knowid)
    end
    else
    begin
       SELECT        
           name, contentType, uploadActionTicketID AS id
       FROM            
           [t_uploadForAction]
       WHERE        
           (actionID_FK = @actionid)
end
```

Comment: what does it mean `didn't work properly`?

Comment: "but it didn't work properly. Could anyone point me in the right direction?", maybe if you tell us what "didn't work properly" means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/297ae/4)

This works

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAttachment_View]
    @knowid int,
    @actionid int   
AS
    if(@actionid is null)
    begin
        SELECT 'Im null'                       
    end
    else
    begin
       SELECT 'Im not null'
    end

EXEC [dbo].[spAttachment_View] @knowid =1 , @actionid = null
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing for null, you may have a better solution with COALESCE where you can provide a default (valid) value in case of null. Otherwise look at Oropeza's solution above.

Comment: Maybe a wrong, but OP question require a select and `coalesce` can't work with that case?.